# rsync to remote location exits with code 12

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rsync, remote-server

I am trying to rsync a local folder to a remote location. This a command that I have run successfully a week ago, but now if i run:

```
    rsync -vrtzu\
        --chown=user:webadm
        --delete
        --exclude-from=.rsyncignore
        FOLDER/
   USER@REMOTE:/DESTINATION
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
zsh:1: no matches found: --usermap=*:USER
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
make: *** [makefile:39: push] Error 12
```

The command is run from a makefile, hence the last line.
I am using a regular WSL2 Ubuntu shell, not zsh.
I am able to ssh into the remote location with USER@REMOTE.
I have also checked that both locations have rsync installed (same version).
Finally, there is plenty of disk space available on the remote location.

Any pointers? What should I be checking to improve my diagnostic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is an rsync bug:

> ```
> zsh:1: no matches found: --usermap=*:USER
> ```

It only happens the remote machine's default shell is `zsh`.

It was fixed somewhere between rsync `3.2.3` (where it's broken) and `3.2.5` (where the bug is gone).

---

You can verify this by passing `-vv` to `rsync`. This prints as one of the first output lines which command invocation rsync is doing on the remote server via SSH.

On a broken version, it prints e.g.:

```bash
... ssh ... rsync --server -vvnlogDtpRe.LsfxCIvu "--usermap=*:user" "--groupmap=*:webadm"
```

On a fixed version, it prints e.g.:

```bash
... ssh ... rsync --server -vvnlogDtpRe.LsfxCIvu "--usermap=\*:user" "--groupmap=\*:webadm"
```

As you can see, they inserted a `\` to fix the string being interpreted by `zsh`.

Comment: It seems like https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#Changes_in_this_version-3.2.4 this one.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the remote shell messes with the command. Not sure exactly why and what it does but it modifies escaping so that the file path becomes invalid.

In your case the shell outputs `--usermap=*:USER` at log in.

The solution is to change the remote (zsh) shell to bash using the `chsh` command

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-s` will fix this issue under rsync 3.2.3 and previous version (like your 3.1.3), as mentioned in rsync's manpage:

> If you  specify  "--chown=foo:bar",  this  is  exactly  the  same  as  specifying "--usermap=*:foo --groupmap=*:bar",  only  easier.  If your shell complains about the wildcards, use --protect-args (-s).

In rsync 3.2.4+ it's "fixed" by a global behavior change, which is mentioned in https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#Changes_in_this_version-3.2.4:

> A new form of arg protection was added that works similarly to the older --protect-args (-s) option but in a way that avoids breaking things like rrsync (the restricted rsync script): rsync now uses backslash escaping for sending "shell-active" characters to the remote shell (such as $(){}<>#& and others).

btw, usually you need to add `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` in addition to your original command, for permission requirements.